# Evaluate Leiningen Code In Project

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen

I have a lein plugin and I need to evaluate its code within the project context.  I can do trivial stuff like this

```
(leiningen.core.eval/eval-in-project project '(+ 1 2))
```

but once I require code from the plugin itself

```
(leiningen.core.eval/eval-in-project 
  project
  '(my-ns/my-fn) 
  '(require '[my-plugin.my-ns :as my-ns])
```

its not on the load path of the target project!  How can I edit the project map to include plugin code within the project?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `eval-in-project` must be the project map. The second argument is the form to evaluate, and the third is an `init` form "*that is evaluated up-front before the main form*". In ["Evaluation in project context"](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PLUGINS.md#evaluating-in-project-context) there's a link to a post explaining [how to avoid "the gilardi scenario"](http://technomancy.us/143), which is defined as:

> The Gilardi Scenario refers to a case where you want to evaluate some code that both loads in a new var and refers to that var in the same piece of code

The issue in your code is that you are defining an alias in the `init` form and expect it to be defined in your main code too.

So, your code might be something like:

```
(defn my-plugin [project & opts]
  (leiningen.core.eval/eval-in-project 
    project
    '(my-plugin.my-ns/my-fn)
    '(require 'my-plugin.my-ns)))
```

Comment: I meant to include project.  My question is really: how can I edit the project map so that it includes the plugin code within the target project.

Comment: Oh, I thought your main issue was the missing project argument. If you really want to update the project map, there's an example in that "Evaluation in project context" based on the swank project. tl,dr: use `project/merge-profiles`. But probably you don't need to edit the project, but just to not define the alias in the `init` third argument. I'll update the answer with what I think should work

Comment: Hi nberger,

your solution still doesn't work because my-plugin.my-ns is not on the classpath of the target project.  I need a way to get it in there.  One solution is to separate out the plugin code into a separate leiningen project but that seems a bit of a kludge.

Answer (score 0):

We need a way to get source code from our plugin into the target project classpath.  Once way is to copy the source from the leiningen classpath into a source folder in the target project

```
(import java.io.File)
(import clojure.lang.RT)
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn copy-src [& name-spaces]
   (doseq [name-space name-spaces]
     (let [
          resource (-> name-space
                       str
                       (.replace "." "/")
                       (.replace "-" "_")
                       (str ".clj"))
          on-classpath (RT/getResource (RT/baseLoader) resource)
          parent-dir (File.
                      (str 
                       ".cljsserve/"
                       (.substring resource 0 (.lastIndexOf resource "/"))))
          src-file (File. (str ".cljsserve/" resource))
          ]
      (.mkdirs parent-dir)
      (with-open [in (io/input-stream on-classpath)]
        (io/copy in src-file)))))
```

We may then update the project map to include our "temp" source folder and eval in project

```
(let [new-project (update-in project [:source-paths] concat [".cljsserve"])]
  (leiningen.core.eval/eval-in-project
   new-project
   '(cljs-server.web/-main)
   '(require 'cljs-server.web)))
```

An alternative is just to put the plugin logic within a separate dependency.  In my case I created a dependency `[cljs-server "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]` and then made my plugin into a wrapper around it

```
(leiningen.core.eval/eval-in-project
 (update-in project [:dependencies] concat [[cljs-server "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]])
   `(cljs-server.web/-main ~port ~ssl? ~ssl-port ~src)
   '(require 'cljs-server.web)) ;cljs-server.web is defined within the dependency
```